# Эрмитаж, Лувр, Белый дом — это топонимы?

Tags: ономастика, топонимика

Как классифицировать собственные названия уникальных недвижимых объектов, таких как Эрмитаж, Лувр, Белый дом? Являются ли они топонимами?

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC

Вот статья со ссылкой на источник (Подольская Н. В. Словарь русской ономастической терминологии / Отв. ред. А. В. Суперанская.) В ней утверждается, что названия зданий - это тоже частный подвид топонима

Comment: Исправьте! 1. ЧастНый. 2.  Подольская Н. В. Словарь русской ономастической терминологии / Отв. ред. А. В. Суперанская.

Comment: И просто доброго слова за указанные ошибки я, конечно, не заслужила.

Comment: Ммм... Спасибо!